# Javascript on JetBrains IDE: assigning the base class type-hinted instance to the parameter type-hinted as a sub-class

Tags: javascript, ide, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Consider the following:

```
let container = document.getElementById('container');
let inp = container.querySelector('#my-input-element');
forceDisabled(inp);
/**
 * @param {HTMLInputElement} inp
 */
function forceDisabled(inp) {
    inp.disabled = true;
}
```

The `inp` would be a valid [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) at runtime. The JetBrains IDE correctly considers its type as being an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). By *"typing"* the function parameter rationally as being `HTMLInputElement`, the IDE complains:

> *Argument type `Element` is not assignable to parameter type `HTMLInputElement`*

The IDE does suggest to *"change the parameter type to `Element`"*; but that would be totally irrational, so that inside of the function not only disables the autocomplete feature, but also complains on "resolving issues" on class-specific methods *(e.g: the methods of [`stepUp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/stepUp) or [`stepDown()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/stepDown) would be flagged as "unresolved")*.

So, what should I do to have the *appropriate "typing hints" to the IDE (not using `*`)* while having the warning resolved?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! [Type-hinting](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wikis/TagType.wiki) the `inp` on declaration should resolve the issue:

```
/** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
let inp = container.querySelector('#my-input-element');
```